# Webpack not detecing proxy for local development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, proxy

I'm having trouble getting a little proxy working with my React app. I'm trying to use a little express server to keep some API keys secret so that my application can make use of a 3rd party API (the github API to be specific). I have a small express app running that I can query to get the API keys out of a `.env` file and attach those keys to my request to the 3rd party API.

Presently, I am able to start the front-end application and the express app simultaneously, and I can query the express app and get a response using my browser.

I'm trying to configure webpack to proxy my requests through this express app. In my `webpack.config.js` file I have:

```js
//
devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
//
```

Front-end application is running on port `8080`, and my Express app is running on port `3000`, both on the `localhost`.

In my React App, for trying to test whether this proxy is being detected/used, I have the following in a component:

```js
//
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/api/secret')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('RES: ', res)
        res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Data: ", data)
        return JSON.stringify(data)
      })
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.username)
  }
//
```

The backend code is super simple at the moment, but here it is:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

// Initialize app
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Configure
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())



app.get('/secret', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200)
  res.send({ aSecret: process.env.<API_KEY> })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is running on port ${port}`))
```

In my `package.json` I have the following (relevant script and dependencies):

```
...
...
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"webpack-dev-server\" \"npm run server\"",
    "server": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

As you can see, in the component I'm (attempting to) making a request to `api/secret` and hoping to get back in the response the API key that I have stored in my `.env`.

When I query this route in my browser using `fetch('http://localhost:3000/secret')` I am able to access the API key successfully, so I know that when I run the `npm run start` script that both the React application and the Express application are starting up simultaneously.

When I click the button in my React component that sends a request to `/api/secret` I get the following output in the browser console (in keeping with the console logs I have in the react component at the moment):
[image: Console output indicating a request made to the URL <code>http://localhost:8080/api/secret</code>, further showing that the proxy I'm trying to set up is not being detected]

I'm just not sure at this point what I'm doing wrong with the `proxy` configuration in the `devServer` webpack configuration.

I can see that the hostname is being automatically prepended to the `/api/secret` in the `fetch` within the React component.

Stated Goal: Webpack successfully detects the proxy server I'm using to server requests to the 3rd party (GitHub) API.

I apologize if this question is a repeat, I've spent several hours researching and fiddling with this configuration and have been unsuccessful in finding out how to configure this. This is my first attempt at spinning up a little proxy server as well. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return res.json()

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/api/secret')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('RES: ', res)
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Data: ", data)
        return JSON.stringify(data)
      })
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.username)
  }
```

Comment: I initially felt that this wasn't correct, but it appears to be working. As usual, a silly error on my part. Thanks for the help.